# Android Bluetooth ScanFilter Partial String Matching

Tags: java, android, regex, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm looking to use a ScanFilter to search for a set of bluetooth devices. I know the address of all these devices starts with 00:A0:50, and then the last 6 digits vary, so all addresses will look like 00:A0:50:XX:XX:XX. I'm looking for a way to use [setDeviceAddress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanFilter.Builder.html#setServiceData) to find devices with addresses beginning with those 6 digits. This takes a string as input. The relevant code is below.

```
ScanFilter cypressFilter = new ScanFilter().Builder()
    //we know that their mac address will always start with 00:A0:50
    //so we should filter out any devices without that
    .setDeviceAddress(/* Address string goes here */)
    .build();
```

I think I'll need to use something like a regular expression for this, but I'm fairly new to Java, Android, and regex, and I'm not sure if I can pass in a regular expression to this function? Looking at the docs, I think I will need a Pattern or Matcher class to find the relevant strings.  However, I'm not sure if this will work with this specific method which wants a specific string as input. I'm surprised it doesn't take an array as input, I would think that would be a more common use case than a single MAC address.

Comment: So, you are looking for a regex to match `00:A0:50:XX:XX:XX` or you are asking if it can be done with regex?

Comment: I edited my question a bit. I'm mainly asking if it can be done with regex, and how that would be structured. If someone provided the specific regex to do it as well that would be great, but that is less important that knowing if/how this can be accomplished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use **regex** & **[Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)** class

use following `regex` to match string address

```
00:A0:50:([A-Fa-f0-9]{2}:){2}[A-Fa-f0-9]
```

### see demo [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oE4nQ9/1)

> I'm surprised it doesn't take an array as input, I would think that
>   would be a more common use case than a single MAC address.

For now you can use loop(i.e for , while.. etc) and match the address

Comment: After testing the demo I think it needs a {2} on the end to capture the last 2 digits instead of just the final one. Otherwise, that's great. I'll look into the pattern class.