# Android BLE. Is it possible to send data to devices on scanning?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an Application that has a BLE device that only shows up on scan when some parameters are sent on scanning.

The App nrf Connect do this task very well (When filter by raw data, and use the `0x02010612435542` raw data parameter).

The device won't show its name, neither it's UUID's, nor manufacturer data. 
On nrf Connect, the only thing it shares is a raw return like this: `0X020106124355420000080390BECB49400400CB500CF` (which is preciselly what I need right now).
And on scan by Mac Address (testing on one unit of the device), it only gets me its rssi)

My question is, just like nrfConnect, how can I code a filter or something like that, that will be sent as a parameter on scanning, so I can find my devices? The devices doesn't have names (it shows N/A on scan), and I can't add a list of Mac Address filters because there will be tons of devices of the same kind, when my application is finished.

```
private List<ScanFilter> scanFilters() {
    List<ScanFilter> list = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();

        ScanFilter scanFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder().build();
        list.add(scanFilter);

        //What kind of filter do I use to send that data on scanning?

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your BLE scanner, you receive `ScanResult` containing an instance of `BluetoothDevice` i.e. the device scanned. At the very least, you should be able to read the BLE address of the device i.e. its hardware address. Use the method:

```
BluetoothDevice.getAddress();
```

This hardware address should have a predefined range, such as starting with "A3:B4" which enables filtering scanRecords. Ask your device manufacturer for how these hardware addresses are generated.

Also, if you know the manufacturer id of the devices you are supporting, you can set a filter based on manufacturer data:

```
ScanFilter scanFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder()
                                .setManufacturerData(manufacturerId, manufacturerData)
                                .build();
```

Note the first two bytes of the manufacturerData array is the manufacturerId.

EDIT: The manufacturerData are part of the bytes array returned by

```
scanResult.getScanRecord().getBytes()
```

The `scanResult` is passed to the `ScanCallback` you've given to `BluetoothLESCanner.startScan(...)`

Comment: Thanks for replying! But here is the deal.... on the official bluetooth Company IDs website [link](http://encurtador.com.br/biAI7)[link] which contains all the manufacturer IDs, there is no ID for the company that develops my device(Company): [link](http://www.cubelec.com.tw/) When I perform a scan based on the MacAddress, the scanRecord result is like this: `[ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6, mServiceUuids=null, mManufacturerSpecificData={}, mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=null]]` . Is it possible that the company just doesn't have/broadcast a manufacturerID ?

Comment: Just send a message to Bluetooth SIG and tell them that you want a company identifier then. Your other option is to use "service data" but then you will get more overhead since a service uuid is 16 bytes (128-bit).

Comment: @Emil , thanks for the feedback, but can you please elaborate? How to use service data and what's the deal about the 16 bytes uuid?

Comment: In my opinion a scanRecord without any manufacturer data is not useable. Have you tried requesting the company for a firmware update that include manufacturer data in the scanRecords ? Also, see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks @matdev, I will digup in your answer and try to figure it out. In the meantime, is there a way to pass `0x02010612435542` as a parameter on scan? I assume it is a hex representation of a `byte[]` right? When I use some online Hex-to-String converter, it translates to `CUB`, which is the device manufacturer's name. Weird, and I don't have idea on how this can be helpful but, there it is. Thanks!

Comment: The bytes array including manufacturer data is returned by scanResult.getScanRecord().getBytes()

Comment: @matdev , yeah, I have gotten the data and was able to parse it to hex. But I still need to scanFilter it correctly (not by address). So, with this data (parsed like this) `{1=06, 67=7B00B4490004405DD9BE90100800004255}` (first one are flags right? General Discovery, no BR/EDR i believe). And, as you said, the first 2 bytes are the manufacturer ID? So, if it is in little endian, manufacturerID would be `0x5542`? The `byte[]`I got was `[2,1,6,18,67,85,66,0,0,8,3,-112,-66,-53,73,64,4,0,74,-76,0,-89,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

Comment: In the byte array of the scan record, the manufacturer data part starts with 0xFF i.e. -1, (followed by the length of the data). Since I don't see -1 in your scan record, it seems your manufacturer does not follow standard conventions: http://dylanh.art/ble/android/2016/09/27/ble-advertising-packets.html

Comment: @matdev thanks for all the support man. Still trying to figure it out here. Do you, by any chance, know how the nrfConnect app works? That thing does exactly what I need to do. Filter by raw data. I just don't know how to do it....

Comment: Well, I "discovered" that the device act as / is a Beacon. So I  may be doing the wrong approach here.

Comment: BLE device can act as beacon while it advertizes as BLE device, it's standard. Try to inspect the result of scanResult.getScanRecord() with the debugger to retrieve the data you see with nrfConnect

Comment: This thing is about to drive me crazy... Retrieve the data is OK. The thing is that I cannot use the raw data provided to scan for it. I have tried scanning for UUID (got it from the manufacturer), Service data and Manufacturer data. The Scan with MAC Address I can do, but it is of no use to me, since I don't know in the future which similar devices will be, So I cannot use specific MAC filter. Didn't try by name either, since the device doesn't have a name advertised. The manufacturer said: for iOS, use UUID, for Android, use the raw data to filter.

Comment: You should be able to use the raw data from the scan record to filter records, on both Android and iOS. If not, the device is not usable in BLE

Comment: Let me see if I got it...
I have to do something like this:
`byte[] dataByteArray = record.getBytes();`
And when I get this result, I use it as a scan filter like `manufacturerData` or `serviceData` or whatever?

Comment: @matdev ,  reading your answer again, you mentioned: `This hardware address should have a predefined range, such as starting with "A3:B4" which enables filtering scanRecords`. Can I filter for a range of MAC Addresses, instead of a specific Address? like `filter from this, to this`, instead of `filter this one`, and `now this one`, `this one`, etc?

Comment: The device manufacturer should be able to tell you if his devices's MAC addresses starts with a predefined value, such as "A3:B4". If yes, then you can do the filtering yourself, based on the MAC address of device scanned

Comment: Yeah, they have a predefined prefix. It's `F8:36:9B`.... Should I use it on the scanFilter itself, like using the prefix + a regex, or on the scanResult ?

Comment: I was thinking on something like:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322388/android-bluetooth-scanfilter-partial-string-matching
Do you think it will work?

Comment: This is similar to my answer i.e. filtering record yourself based on MAC address. Please accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks man. If I could upvote you, I would. As soon as I figure it out for good, I will post it here.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution to my problem.

It wasn't the way I was thinking, but thanks to @matdev, I managed to figure it out somehow. And it does not answer the main question, i.e. if it is possible to send data to devices on scan, but, the solution works for me.

First, I made a filter by name, in which the device `name == null`.

```
private List<ScanFilter> scanFilters() {
    List<ScanFilter> list = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();

    ScanFilter scanFilterName = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceName(null).build();

    list.add(scanFilterName);

    return list;
}
```

It gave me a huge list with tons of devices. So I added another filter, but this time, on the `scanResult()`. This other filter is by `MAC Address` suffix, as pointed by @matdev, it is the same for my devices.

```
private Set<String> btDeviceData = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
private ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {

        BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();

        ScanRecord record = result.getScanRecord();
        byte[] dataByteArray = record.getBytes();

        if (device.getAddress().startsWith("F8:36:9B")) {

            btDeviceData.add(device.getAddress());
        }
    }
};
```

By doing this, I got a list (`Set` to be specific) with only the devices I was looking for.