# Android BLE. Is it possible to use a regex as a filter to scan for Mac Address?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have to build an App that scans for BLE devices, and return it's data.
The devices won't show on scan, unless I use a filter.

UUID is not an option, and the device does not broadcast it's name (It shows N/A when scanned with `nrfConnect`.

I am trying to scan it by MAC Address. BUT, I do not know the MAC Addresses, since it can be any device of it's kind, so the App won't previously know the MAC Address of the device.

I already know that the device have a prefix on it's Address which is `F8:36:9B`. The thing is the suffix. How can I (and if it is possible to) make a regex to pass as a parameter to find all possible matches of the Device MAC Address?

The regex per se, I have, `([A-Fa-f0-9]{2}:){2}[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}`, which I got from [Android Bluetooth ScanFilter Partial String Matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322388/android-bluetooth-scanfilter-partial-string-matching).

I just don't know how to implement it on the scanFilter.

```
ScanFilter filterMac = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress(/**THE_SUFIX_AND_REGEX*/).build();
```

Is it possible? If it is, then how?

Everything I tried, I get this error:

> Error: invalid device address

I have tried generating all the possible matches using `for` loops and saving it to an `ArrayList`, and then adding it to the list of filters, but I get an `OutOfMemoryException`, since the result is over 16million possibilities.

Comment: Can't you scan for all devices in range. 

Get their mac addresses in a list. 


Then compare this subset of mac addresses to your regex, to find matches after the fact? Or to minimise the list you need to rescan for?

Comment: @Blundell, thanks for the reply. Those devices seems to only show on scan, when a filter is added.
I have tried to add some specific MAC Addresses on the filter, and they showed up. But without the filter, it finds lots of devices, but do not find any of the ones I need.

Comment: A scan with no filter should return all devices in the proximity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of struggle, I found a solution to my problem.
It does not answer the question per se, i.e. if it's possible to use a regex as a filter to scan for MAC Address.
But, I managed to properly scan for the devices I needed.
This is what I did:

First of all, I made a filter by name. Yes, name, the device have no name. So I had to think... What if, I filter by name, to scan for devices whose `name == null`?

```
private List<ScanFilter> scanFilters() {
    List<ScanFilter> list = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
    
    ScanFilter scanFilterName = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceName(null).build();
    
    list.add(scanFilterName);
    
    return list;
}
```

Well, it worked! But, it returned me not only the devices I needed, but tons of other devices, alongside with them. It was a mess in my scan, so how to refine the filter to give me only those ones I needed?
The second filter (which wasn't on the `scanFilters()`method above, it was on the `scanResult`), was by MAC Address prefix (which is the same for my devices).

```
private Set<String> btDevice = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

private ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {

        BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
        
        ScanRecord record = result.getScanRecord();
        byte[] dataByteArray = record.getBytes();

        if (device.getAddress().startsWith("F8:36:9B")) {
            btDevice.add(device.getAddress());
        }
    }
};
```

And voilá, I got a scan with only the devices I needed.
I still want to know if the main question is possible, i.e. if we can use a regex on the `scanFilter()`, to filter a range of something (in this case, MAC Address). So, if someone have a solution to this, please feel free to answer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not possible with filters. You must filter yourself...like you did already

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback!